# more tag in the $post->content when get_pages were used

Tags: pages, templates

I used get_pages() to get the content of the child pages of a page. Although the excerpt can also be an answer but is there any other way to display the contents of the page before the more tag when I use the get_pages()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the WordPress function [`get_extended`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_extended) to fetch the different parts of a string (the part before and the part after the `<!--more-->` tag). `get_extended` returns an array with three keys, of which the keys `main` and `extended` are important: `$arr['main']` contains the part before the more tag, and `$arr['extended']` the part after the more tag.

This would yield something like:

```
// Fetch post content
$content = get_post_field( 'post_content', get_the_ID() );

// Get content parts
$content_parts = get_extended( $content );

// Output part before <!--more--> tag
echo $content_parts['main'];
```